# I'm getting Invalid end tag error in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, compiler-errors, vue-component

I'm developing a project with VueJS. Now I am only including a ready-made template in the Vue project. I haven't written any vue code yet. But I keep getting compile errors. I am sure there is no error in my code. But the error just doesn't go away. I share with you my codes and error message in the component I got an error.

```
<div class="infotechno-hero infotechno-bg">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row align-items-center">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                <div class="infotechno-hero-text  wow move-up">
                    <h6>IT Design  Consulting </h6>
                    <h1 class="font-weight--reguler mb-15">Facilitate All <br>  Local IT-related Service Providers  </h1>
                    <p>Highly Tailored IT Design, Management  Support Services. </p>
                    <div class="hero-button  mt-30">
                        <a href="#" class="ht-btn ht-btn-md">Get details</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                <div class="infotechno-hero-inner-images">
                    <div class="infotechno-inner-one">
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="assets\images\hero\home-infotechno-main-slider-slide-01-image-01.png" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="infotechno-inner-two  wow move-up">
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="assets\images\hero\home-infotechno-main-slider-slide-01-image-02.png" alt="" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you try replacing your `<br>` with `<br />` ?

Comment: Thank you for your comments but didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where is your template tags? You have to write your divs in a template in vue files.
You can look at there for more info: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html

```
<template>
  <div class="infotechno-hero infotechno-bg">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row align-items-center">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
          <div class="infotechno-hero-text wow move-up">
            <h6>IT Design Consulting</h6>
            <h1 class="font-weight--reguler mb-15">
              Facilitate All
              <br />Local IT-related Service Providers
            </h1>
            <p>Highly Tailored IT Design, Management Support Services.</p>
            <div class="hero-button mt-30">
              <a href="#" class="ht-btn ht-btn-md">Get details</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
          <div class="infotechno-hero-inner-images">
            <div class="infotechno-inner-one">
              <img class="img-fluid" src="assets\images\hero\home-infotechno-main-slider-slide-01-image-01.png" alt />
            </div>
            <div class="infotechno-inner-two wow move-up">
              <img class="img-fluid" src="assets\images\hero\home-infotechno-main-slider-slide-01-image-02.png" alt />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: I already use <template> </template> tags in the app.vue file, but I didn't know I had to use it in each vue file. Adding these tags solved the problem. Thank you

Comment: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/application.html#mounting-the-app doesn't seem like you need to in vue 3?